# Phonegap Alternative

Tags: html, cordova, mobile, html5-audio

Is there an alternative for phonegap that supports changing playback rate for media (esp. audio)?

it looks that they don't have a property for that:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html

Comment: have you had a look at sencha touch

Comment: @kalpaitch I have. and couldn't find anything related to the rate docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Audio

Answer (score 1):

The `audio` and `video` elements in HTML5 supports changing playback rates according to the spec. Unfortunately, this doesn't work in all players. I've managed to make it work everywhere except on Android and I expect wide browser support to be available soon, since the android developer team is working on it.

If you get into the nitty gritty details, note that setting playback rate only works on all platforms after you have received a `timeupdate` event where the `currentTime` attribute has been set to a nonzero number, except on iOS where it only works if `currentTime` is zero (so to make it work cross platform, you have to set it twice).